# ffmpeg: Time information does not match video duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using tvheadend to record broadcasts to disc (running ubuntu). Later, I'm playing the files using players like MX Videoplayer or IJK player. Sometimes, the time information of the media files is weired. E.g., using

```
ffprobe -i some-file.ts
```

shows a lenght of 10 hours or even 20 hours, although the recording is only 2 hours long. Is this a ffmpeg bug? What can be done to get the correct media length?

Here is the ffprobe output of the original file after recording it on disc:

```
ffprobe version N-85175-ga434657 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration:
  libavutil      55. 59.100 / 55. 59.100
  libavcodec     57. 90.100 / 57. 90.100
  libavformat    57. 72.100 / 57. 72.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 83.100 /  6. 83.100
  libswscale      4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
[mp3 @ 0x24caef0] Header missing
[mpeg2video @ 0x24817b0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mp3 @ 0x24caef0] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x24817b0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 3 times
[mp3 @ 0x24caef0] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x24817b0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mp3 @ 0x24caef0] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x24817b0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mp3 @ 0x24caef0] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x24817b0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mp3 @ 0x24caef0] Header missing
    Last message repeated 9 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x24817b0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mp3 @ 0x24caef0] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x24817b0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mp3 @ 0x24caef0] Header missing
    Last message repeated 11 times
[mpeg2video @ 0x24817b0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mp3 @ 0x24caef0] Header missing
    Last message repeated 318 times
[mpegts @ 0x247cd40] decoding for stream 4 failed
[mpegts @ 0x247cd40] start time for stream 3 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 0x247cd40] PES packet size mismatch
    Last message repeated 2 times
[mpegts @ 0x247cd40] Could not find codec parameters for stream 4 (Audio: mp3, 0 channels, s16p): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from '30d0b11f21ce831b56cc306d9c4a18c0.backup':
  Duration: 10:03:33.54, start: 60774.296367, bitrate: 1883 kb/s
  Program 12101
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ?RTL Television
      service_provider: ?Unitymedia
    Stream #0:0[0x20b]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x20c](ger): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
Stream #0:2[0x20d](ger): Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s
Stream #0:3[0x60f](ger): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
  No Program
Stream #0:4[0x210]: Audio: mp3, 0 channels, s16p
```

Here is the output of ffprobe somefile -show_entries stream=index,start_time,duration -of compact -v 0:

```
program|stream|index=0|start_time=88858.718567|duration=8129.120000
stream|index=1|start_time=88858.104267|duration=8129.496000
stream|index=2|start_time=88858.104289|duration=8129.498833
stream|index=3|start_time=60774.296367|duration=36213.542200

stream|index=0|start_time=88858.718567|duration=8129.120000
stream|index=1|start_time=88858.104267|duration=8129.496000
stream|index=2|start_time=88858.104289|duration=8129.498833
stream|index=3|start_time=60774.296367|duration=36213.542200
stream|index=4|start_time=60774.296367|duration=8129.520000
```

Comment: Show the full log from ffprobe.

Comment: Share output of `ffprobe somefile -show_entries stream=index,start_time,duration -of compact -v 0`

Comment: Any idea? Mulvya?